# What data type does a number have in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

```
A <= 3 * B;
```

In the above statement is `3` an integer or a natural number. If it's a natural number, what if I use a negative number there. Does VHDL recognize it as an integer?

Comment: Integer literals like your `3` are an *universal integer*. `integer` and `natural` are sub types of universal integer.

Answer (score 3):

Integer literals are of the anonymous predefined type `universal_integer`. They are implicitly converted to the required (sub-)type, e.g. `integer` or `natural`, for your operator `*`. See also IEEE Std. 1076-2008, para. 5.2.3.1.

Thus, if you specify the term `-3`, this is parsed as a simple expression composed of the minus sign `-` and the abstract (decimal) literal 3. The number 3 will be of type `universal_integer`, and after applying the sign operator, it is still of the same type. (Thanks to @user1155120 for the clarification.)
After that, the conversion of the expression `-3` will fail, if your operator requires a `natural`.

Same applies for floating-point literals which are of the anonymous predefined type `universal_real`, see also para. 5.2.5.1.

Operands of any integer type, can be converted to any floating point type and vice versa. The conversion from floating point to integer takes place using rounding to the nearest integer. Floating point values with a fractional part of 0.5 are either rounded up or down, see also para. 9.3.6.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @user1155120 Fixed it, I hope. It would be much clearer in the standard, if para. 5.2.3.1 would have a forward reference to para. 15.5 (as in the glossary). For me an _integer_ also includes negative numbers, but it is not true here.

Comment: @user1155120 Yes, an _integer type_  can cover negative numbers. But, the BNF rule named _integer_ can **not** because it expands only to digits and underlines (15.5.2). Thus, integer literals are either positive or zero. And this is what I found confusing in the written text. The formal notation is unambigous, of course.